# Send $_GET or $_POST in functions

Tags: php, post

I want get parameters from a form and send `caption` parameter to a function to change character encoding!

**PHP Code**

```
if (isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['password'])){
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];
    $captione  = $_GET['caption'];
    echo $captione.'<br>';
    echo convert_u($captione);
}else{
    loginForm();
}

function convert_u($cap){
    $cap = str_replace('ض','"\u0636"',$cap);
    $cap = str_replace('ص','"\u0635"',$cap);
    $cap = str_replace('ث','"\u062b"',$cap);
    return $cap;
}
```

The form `enctype` is `multipart/form-data`.

When I type `convert_u('حامد');` or `convert_u($parameter);` this works.

But when send parameter that receive from `$_GET` and `$_POST` it doesn't work!!

Answer (score 0):

Add a encoding tag to your form tag like

```
<form accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

Comment: my promles: i can't send $_POST['evry thing'] to function